# MySQL how to insert into a table with a SELECT UNION ALL and additional parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

The data on `slds` consists of `protocol_id` (foreign key for `protocols`), `tld_id` (foreign key for `tlds`) and `sld_name`.

I need to select the primary key values from `protocols` and `tlds`, then insert both keys and the remaining `sld_name` into `slds`.

I can't seem to structure the "google" in the correct place.  What am I missing here?

```
INSERT INTO `slds` (sld_name, protocol_id, tld_id)
"google",
SELECT `id` FROM `protocols`
WHERE `protocol_name`="https"
UNION ALL
SELECT `id` FROM `tlds`
WHERE `tld_name`="com"
```

Also, assuming this is possible, how can I insert **n** rows using this method?

Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION ALL` joins ROWs. What you want is a single value:

```
INSERT INTO slds (sld_name, protocol_id, tld_id)
SELECT
    'google',
    (SELECT id FROM protocols WHERE protocol_name = 'https'),
    (SELECT id FROM tlds WHERE tld_name = 'com');
```